# Python, lxml - get a sibling tag's (grand)child's text

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, siblings, dspace

I have an XML to parse which is proving really tricky for me.

```
<bundles>
  <bundle>
    <bitstreams>
      <bitstream>
        <id>1234</id>
      </bitstream>
    </bitstream>
    <name>FOO</name>
  </bundle>
  <bundle> ... </bundle>
</bundles>
```

I would like to iterate through this XML and locate all the **id** values inside of the **bitstreams** for a **bundle** where the **name** element's value is 'FOO'. I'm not interested in any bundles not named 'FOO', and there may be any number of bundles and any number of bitstreams in the bundles.

I have been using `tree.findall('./bundle/name')` to find the FOO bundle but this just returns a list that I can't step through for the **id** values:

```
for node in tree.findall('./bundle/name'):
if node.text == 'FOO':
 id_values = tree.findall('./bundle/bitstreams/bitstream/id')
 for value in id_values:
     print value.text
```

This prints out *all* the id values, not those of the bundle 'FOO'.

How can I iterate through this tree, locate the **bundle** with the **name** FOO, take this **bundle** node and collect the **id** values nested in it? Is the XPath argument incorrect here?

I'm working in Python, with `lxml` bindings - but any XML parser I believe would be alright; these aren't large XML trees.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `xpath` to achieve the purpose. Following Python code works perfect:

```
import libxml2
data = """
<bundles>
  <bundle>
    <bitstreams>
      <bitstream>
        <id>1234</id>
      </bitstream>
    </bitstreams>
    <name>FOO</name>
  </bundle>
</bundles>
"""
doc = xmllib2.parseDoc(data)
for node in doc.xpathEval('/bundles/bundle/name[.="FOO"]/../bitstreams/bitstream/id'):
    print node
```

or using `lxml` (`data` is the same as in the example above):

```
from lxml import etree

bundles = etree.fromstring(data)

for node in bundles.xpath('bundle/name[.="FOO"]/../bitstreams/bitstream/id'):
    print(node.text)
```

outputs:

```
1234
```

If the `<bitstreams>` element always precedes the `<name>` element, you can also use the more efficient xpath expression:

```
'bundle/name[.="FOO"]/preceding-sibling::bitstreams/bitstream/id'
```

Comment: basically u find bundle with name foo .. then go to the parent node and traverse back to bitstream id ...

Comment: Added an `lxml` example also, since it was what the OP was using. Hope that's all right.

Comment: Yes, this worked correctly. I was completely misunderstanding XPath in lxml.

Answer (score 2):

One of your questions was "Is the XPath argument incorrect here?". Well, `findall()` doesn't accept XPath expressions. It uses a simplified version called [ElementPath](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath). Also, your second call to `findall()` is not related in any way to the result of the first one, so it will just return `id`s of all `bundle`s.

A slight modification to your code should also work (it's basically the same as the XPath expression):

```
for node in tree.findall('./bundle/name'):
    if node.text != 'FOO':
        continue
    id_values = node.getparent().findall('./bitstreams/bitstream/id')
    for value in id_values:
        print value.text
```